# How to use vue to achieve a click to make the input box bigger

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello everyone~ At present, I have just come into contact with `vue`. There is a project that needs to make the input box higher after clicking the button, but I have difficulty writing the effect!
I would like to ask everyone to help me see if there is a mistake in the code. ? Thank you all for your help!

HTML

```
<div id="myApp">

   <textarea class="message" placeholder="pleace enter you message" :class="expand_message"></textarea>
   <a href="javascript:;" @click="btnClick">click</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.message{
  display: block;
}

.expand_message{
  height: 300px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
let myApp = new Vue({
  el:"#myApp",
  data:{
    expand_message:true
  },
  methods:{
    btnClick: function(){
    // 點擊變紅色與回復原狀
    this.expand_message = !this.expand_message;
    },
  },
});
```

[My program template](https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/BaZKeeL?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so first off try to keep code on stackoverflow. e.g. in your question.

```
<div id="myApp">
   <textarea placeholder="pleace enter you message" :class="['message', expand_message ? 'expand_message' : null]"></textarea>
   <button @click="btnClick">click</button>
</div>
```

And to get your animation, you can not transition on height however you can transition on max height:

```
.message{
  display: block;
  max-height: 40px;
  height: 300px;
  transition: max-height ease-out 1s;
}

.expand_message{
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: First of all~Thank you for telling me these methods!
In addition, I would like to ask you to help me see, if I want to change slowly while getting higher, instead of getting higher at once, am I right?

Sorry just started learning everything There is still a lot of unclear
https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/mdwPZEP

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
:class="{'expand_message': expand_message}"
```